# Merging lines of an array

Tags: php, algorithm, array

I've got an array like this, which is a result from a Google analytics request. I asked for the amount of visits for the last three months.

```
$statPerMonth
array (size=2)
  '08' =>     // The month (August)
    array (size=34)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '08' (length=2) // Month again
          1 => string 'admin.testweb.fr' (length=19) // host
          2 => string '1' (length=1)  // amount of visits
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '08' (length=2)
          1 => string 'audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr' (length=38)
          2 => string '6' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '08' (length=2)
          1 => string 'www.audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr' (length=31)
          2 => string '9' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '08' (length=2)
          1 => string 'carrosserie-abberis.reseau-fivestar.fr' (length=38)
          2 => string '7' (length=1)
'07' => 
    array (size=47)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '07' (length=2)
          1 => string 'www.anothersite.testweb.fr' (length=13)
          2 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '07' (length=2)
          1 => string 'admin.testweb.fr' (length=16)
          2 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '07' (length=2)
          1 => string 'admin.testweb.fr' (length=19)
          2 => string '1' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '07' (length=2)
          1 => string 'audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr' (length=38)
          2 => string '20' (length=2)
      4 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '07' (length=2)
          1 => string 'www.admin.testweb.fr' (length=19)
          2 => string '1' (length=1)
```

This array represents **the amount of visits for my websites** but you can see that the values **[‘08’][‘1’]** and **[‘08’][‘2’]** are identical (only 'www.' differs) I want to merge those cells and add their value (because it’s the same site !) in order to get the total amount of visits for a site with it’s two hostnames.

Consider $sites as an array of Site Object (websites). the `getHost()` method will return the site host for example ‘my-host.fr’ without the 'www' consider `$statsPerMonth` array explained above

Finally, consider this algorithm:

```
foreach ($statsPerMonth as $actualMonth => $stats) {
            foreach($sites as $site) {
                $siteHost = $site->getHost();
                foreach ($stats as $row) {
                    if (strstr($row['1'], $siteHost)) {
                        if(isset($globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost])) {
                            $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] + $row['2'];
                        } else {
                            $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = 0;
                            $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] + $row['2'];
                        }
                    }
                    if(!isset($globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost])) {
                        $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This algorithm returns the `$globalStats` array in this form:

```
array (size=3)
  '08' => 
    array (size=43)
      'carrosserie-la-cascade.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 1
      'audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 15
      'carrosserie-abberis-fivestar.fr' => int 16
      'carrosserie-arenales-jonathan.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 0
'07' => 
    array (size=43)
      'carrosserie-la-cascade.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 2
      'audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 20
      'carrosserie-abberis-fivestar.fr' => int 0
      'carrosserie-arenales-jonathan.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 4
'06' => 
    array (size=43)
      'carrosserie-la-cascade.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 0
      'audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 29
      'carrosserie-abberis-fivestar.fr' => int 0
      'carrosserie-arenales-jonathan.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 4
```

This is exactly what I want but I think we can improve this algorithm to make it more efficient (because the arrays are big). Any ideas about how to make this algorithm better?

Comment: Are the sites returned in any specific order?

Answer (score 1):

The innermost loop body can be simplified. Instead of this:

> ```
> if (strstr($row['1'], $siteHost)) {
>     if(isset($globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost])) {
>         $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] + $row['2'];
>     } else {
>         $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = 0;
>         $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] + $row['2'];
>     }
> }
> if(!isset($globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost])) {
>     $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = 0;
> }
> ```

I think this is equivalent:

```
if (strstr($row[1], $siteHost)) {
    if (!isset($globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost])) {
        $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = 0;
    }
    $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] += $row[2];
}
```

(I also removed the quotes around the array indexes 1 and 2, I don't think you needed them.)

But the bigger improvement will be to cur out the `foreach($sites as $site)` loop. Think about it, for each site on your list, you re-process all the arrays for the given month. It would be better to process the stats only once. For this you will need a helper function `getCanonicalSiteName` that will give you, for example, `audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr` for both `audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr` and `www.audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr` in the processed array. Something like this (untested):

```
foreach ($statsPerMonth as $actualMonth => $stats) {
    foreach ($stats as $row) {
        $siteHost = getCanonicalSiteName($row[1]);
        if (!isset($globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost])) {
            $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = 0;
        }
        $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] += $row[2];
    }
}
```